# Confused about the role of a query language

Tags: sql, database, vb6

So, I haven't had any luck finding any articles or forum posts that have explained to me how exactly a query language works in conjunction with a general use programming language like c++ or vb. So I guess it wont hurt to ask >.<

Basically, I've been having a hard time understanding what the roles of the query language are ( we'll use SQL as an example for query language and VB6 for norm language) if i'm creating a  simple database query that fills a table with normal information (first name, last name, address etc). I somewhat know the steps in setting up a program like  this using ado objects for the connection and whatnot, but how do we decide which language of the 2 gets used for certain things ? Does vb6 specifically handle the basics like loops, if else's, declarations of your vars, and SQL specifically handles things like connecting to the database and doing the searching, filtering and sorting ? Is it possible to do certain general use vb6 actions (loops or conditionals) in SQL syntax instead ? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL is a language to query a database. SQL is an [ISO standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=53681) and relational database vendors implement to the ISO standard and then add on their own customizations.  For example in SQL Server it is called T-SQL and in Oracle it is called PL-SQL.  They both implement ISO standards and so each will have identical queries for a simple select like

```
select columname from tablename where columnname=1
```

However, each have different syntax for string functions, date functions, etc....

The ISO SQL standard by design is not a full procedural language with looping, subroutines, ect as in a full procedural language like VB.

However, each vendor has added capabilities to their version to add some of this functionality in.

For example both T-SQL and PL-SQL can "loop" through records using various constructs in their language.

There is also a difference when working with data that many developers are not well in tuned with.  That is set based operations vs. procedural based.

Databases can work with procedural constructs but are often more performant with set based.  A developer who is not versed in this concept may end up creating a very innefficient query.  [Here's an example of this discussion](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/2019/set-based-vs-procedural.html).

With any situation you have to weight out the pro's/con's of where it is best to do this work.

I tend to favor using procedural constructs such as loops in the language I am using over SQL.  I find it easier to maintain and the language I am using offers more powerful syntax for me to get the job done.

However, I keep both options as a tool in the toolbox.  For example, I have written data conversion scripts in SQL and in this case I have used the looping constructs in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Usually programming language are executed in the client side (app server too), and query languages are executed in the db server, so in the end it depends where you want to put all the work. Sometimes you can put lot of work in the client side by doing all the calculations with the programming language and other times  you want to use more the db server and you end up using the query language or even better tsql/psql or whatever.

Comment: I think this answer fits the question asked *far better* than the others presented.  However perhaps the original question posed wasn't what the OP was really after, instead wanting to know the answer to something like "What does SQL do?"

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases are designed to manage data.  In particular, they provide an efficient mechanism for managing memory, disk, and processors for large quantities of data.  In addition, relational databases can handle multiple clients, guarantee transactional integrity, security, backups, persistence, and numerous other functions.

In general, if you are using an RDBMS with another language, you want to design the data structure first and then think about the API (applications programming interface) between the two.  This is particularly true when you have an app/server relationship.

For a "simple" type of application, which uses a lot of data but with minimal or batch changes to it, you want to move as much of the processing into the database as is reasonable.  Here are things you do not want to do:

1. Use queries to load things into arrays, and then do array manipulations at the language level.  SQL provides joins for this.
2. Load data into an array and do manipulations and summaries on the array.  SQL provides aggregations for this.
3. Save data into a file to have a backup.  Databases provide backup mechanisms.

If you data fits into an array or on an Excel spreadsheet, it is often sufficient to get started with the data stored there.  Only when you start to expand the needs (multiple clients, security, integration with other data) do the advantages of a database become more apparent.

These are just for guidance and to give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of doing what where, do as much as is sensible in SQL (given it runs on a server) as you can.

So for instance don't do stuff like this (psuedo code)

```
foreach(row in "Select * from Orders")
  if (row[CustomerID] = 876)
    Display(row)
```

Do

```
foreach(row in "Select * from Orders where CustomerId = 876")
  Display(row)
```

First it's likely Orders is indexed by CustomerID so it will find all 876s order way quicker.

Second to do the first one you just sucked every record in that table into the client's memory space probably across your network.

What language is used is essentially irrelevant, you could invent your own DBMS with it's own language.

It's where you do what processing that matters. It's Rule with exceptions, but the essential idea is let your backend do as much as it can.